# How to get Gather in Graphdef

Tags: tensorflow

Seems both Gather and GatherV2 are supported by TF, but I can not get Gather in my GraphDef using TF 1.8+, how could I get Gather in graphdef in TF latest version like 1.13?

```
indices = tf.constant([0, 1, 1])
x = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3],
                 [4, 5, 6],
                 [7, 8, 9]])
result = tf.gather(x, indices, axis=1)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    out = sess.run(result)
    print(out)
    print(sess.graph_def)
```

Comment: What's a bit confusing is that official doc still suggests v1: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather